# Change default screen option value for posts per page

Tags: posts, list, screen-options

I want to change the default screen option value for posts per page in the wp-admin area when listing posts in `pending` mode. The default value is set to `20`.

Changing the value directly in the Screen Options tab will only affect the user, not all users like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718721/change-default-screen-options-posts-per-page-value-in-wordpress-admin-through-fu) suggests.

Any workable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an addiction to [@KrzysiekDróżdż answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141714/35541).

When viewing a specific post status the url query string variable `'post_status'`, is set to the name of the status, so you can use `$_GET['post_status']` to narrow the effect of @KrzysiekDróżdż code only for pending posts:

```
function my_edit_per_page( $result, $option, $user ) {
  $status = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'post_status', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  if ( $status === 'pending' && (int) $result < 1 )
  return 20; // or whatever you want
}
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_post_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );  // for posts
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I'll mark this as correct given that it answers the initial question more accurately.

Answer (score 3):

It won't be very hard to do. Just add this to your functions.php or into your plugin:

```
function my_edit_per_page( $result, $option, $user ) {
    if ( (int)$result < 1 )
        return 20; // or whatever you want
}
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_page_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );  // for pages
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_post_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );  // for posts
```

This way you will change the default value. So if user changes it, it will remember user's choice.

The only problem is that this setting is common for entire post type editor. I'm afraid it won't be so easy to set it depending on post status (and not breaking anything).

Comment: Outstanding. And you are absolutely right, the value is the same regardless of post status.

Comment: I've added the above to the functions.php of my theme and works great in Posts but unfortunately Pages still showing as 20 - any changes in WP versions since this was written?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand why the choice to compare to `< 1` from the other answers. Also, if `$result` was zero (and it can't be), the function won't return anything.

I'm using it like this to force a minimum of 50 items per page in an array of pages. Add @gmazzap `$status` code if needed.

```
$perpages = ['flamingo_inbound_messages', 'wpcf7_contact_forms', 'plugins', 'edit_post', 'edit_page'];

foreach($perpages as $option) {
    add_filter( "get_user_option_{$option}_per_page", function ( $result, $option, $user ) {
        if ( (int)$result < 50 ) $result = 50;
        return $result;
    }, 9999, 3 );
}
```

Sometimes, it's not obvious nor easy to find the page name used in the option. I've looked for them directly in the database. Just apply some number on a page and look for it as the `meta_value` in `wp_usermeta`:

> [image: screenshot from wp-admin]

---

> [image: screenshot from the database]