# Change default screen option value for media items per page (in media library)

Tags: media-library, screen-options

I want to remove pagination by changing the default screen option value for **posts per page**, **pages per page** and **media items per page**, in the admin area, to `999`. The default value is set to `20`. I found the answer I need (I have pasted below from @KrzysiekDróżdż's answer in this question: [Change default screen option value for posts per page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141709/change-default-screen-option-value-for-posts-per-page)) but am looking to also add a filter for the media library so it's consistent for all areas of the admin.

```
function my_edit_per_page( $result, $option, $user ) {
    if ( (int)$result < 1 )
        return 20; // or whatever you want
}
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_page_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );  // for pages
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_post_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );  // for posts
```

I've tried these, to no avail:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_media_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );  // for media library
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_media_item_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );  // for media library
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_media_items_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );  // for media library
```

Comment: Note that you need a `return $result;` after the `return 20;` to cover custom pagination values. Otherwise changing the pagination amount won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `upload_per_page`:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_edit_upload_per_page', 'my_edit_per_page', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Do you have a reference for how you knew that? My Google searches do not find me any sort of filter listings explaining any of them: `get_user_option_edit_page_per_page`, `get_user_option_edit_post_per_page` or `get_user_option_edit_upload_per_page`

Comment: It's sneakily buried in `wp_edit_attachments_query()`, which is used by `WP_Media_List_Table`. But TBH I cheated & just inspected the ID of the screen options field in Firebug ;)

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the response, clarification...and honesty :)

Comment: Note that the original poster's functin needs a `return $result;` after the `return 20;` to cover custom pagination values. Otherwise changing the pagination amount won't work. – guidod just now   edit

Answer (score 5):

Since 2.9.0 version of *wordpress* the right way to change default screen option value for media **items per page** (in **media library**) is as follows:

```
function my_edit_media_per_page(){
    $media_per_page = 200; //or whatever you want
    return $media_per_page;
}

add_filter( 'upload_per_page', 'my_edit_media_per_page', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value to 999 will screw up most wordpress hosting, I do not know whether it is PHP or Wordpress but I have tried 500 and it completely wrecks that feature. This is particularly true of images in media library, there seems to be a different setting for grid and list, so you still have access to list but if you select grid again you get a white screen of death.  Now I have to go in the backend and try and figure out what field in what table holds the setting.